# Connecting to JMX server in spring throws exception!

Tags: java, jmx, spring-3

So when I try to connect to jmx from jconsole I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 78.84.17.116; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
    ...
```

I was trying to connect to such url in jconsole: `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://78.84.17.116:43030/test`

My jmx spring configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:mbean-server />

    <bean id="jmxExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter">
        <property name="server" ref="jmxServer" />
        <property name="assembler">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
                <property name="attributeSource">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="SpringBeans:name=hibernateStatisticsMBean"
                    value-ref="hibernateStatisticsMBean" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmxServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean"
        p:locateExistingServerIfPossible="false" />

    <bean id="serverConnector"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean"
        depends-on="rmiRegistry" p:objectName="connector:name=rmi"
        p:serviceUrl="service:jmx:rmi://78.84.17.116/jndi/rmi://localhost:43030/test" />

    <bean name="hibernateStatisticsMBean" class="org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService">
        <property name="statisticsEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="rmiRegistry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
        <property name="port" value="43030" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

What could I be doing wrong that jconsole doesn't want to connect to this jmx server? And what does `test` in the end of jmx url mean? I just saw that it like that in a tutorial so I wrote the same in my url.

**Edit 1:**
When I run `netstat -ntlp` on server I get this:
tcp6       0      0 :::10099                :::*                    LISTEN      10754/java

Where 10754 is the right java application. Is that correct? Running telnet *.*.*.* on 10099 I get a message that it connected to it too. So I guess it's not firewall on server side?

**Edit 2:**
Okay well I'm trying now (and the exception bellow was thrown on server too) to run the app on my local environment (in Eclipse) and I guessing that it ain't server problem because all the same things happen.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConnector' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hw-common-jmx.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:43030/test]: javax.naming.NoPermissionException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at star.Server.main(Server.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:43030/test]: javax.naming.NoPermissionException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(RMIConnectorServer.java:804)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:417)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(ConnectorServerFactoryBean.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoPermissionException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:126)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.bind(GenericURLContext.java:208)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:400)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:625)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:412)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:359)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(RegistryContext.java:120)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry
    at sun.management.jmxremote.SingleEntryRegistry.bind(SingleEntryRegistry.java:61)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Could the problem be in configuration? Could someone verify that my configuration is correct?

**Edit 3:**
I get this each time when I start the app. I guess that is the problem. It happens both on server and my machine..

```
01:40:21.588 [main] INFO  org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean - Looking for RMI registry at port '38457'
01:40:21.654 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean - RMI registry access threw exception
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 188.40.111.83; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:601) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:322) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.list(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.testRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:281) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:259) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:236) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.getRegistry(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:193) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiRegistryFactoryBean.java:164) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:281) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at star.Server.main(Server.java:31) [star-engine-13.05.11.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:180) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595) ~[na:1.6.0_12]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I have no experience with JMX at all but it smells like a Firewall.

Comment: yeah firewall or the service is not up, as the 'Connection is refused'.

Comment: @erhan, hmm, what should i do if it's server firewall? i'm a little blind on firewalls.

Comment: if you use tomcat as container, i remember that there was a jmx.port config in somewhere in catalina.properties. You have to allow incomming/outgoing comminication over the jmx port.

Comment: @erhan, umm well this is not a web app at all so I don't use any tomcat or jetty server for it.. but for the webapps i use jetty.

Comment: whatever you develops, you could still watch using some tools (on Windows exp. Zonealarm) outgoing traffic, or even with Wireshark on which port  the request is delivered.

Comment: how does that solves the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add the following system properties to disable security:

```
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=39600
```

Comment: Yep. You should add them to command line (if your are running from a command line) or to some kind of JAVA_OPTS if you are running server

Comment: @tarlog, so did as you said and I get this exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConnector' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hw-common-jmx.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:39600/myconnector]: javax.naming.NoPermissionException [Root exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.AccessException: Cannot modify this registry]` Need stack trace?

Comment: Any idea what does the access exceptions mean?

Comment: do you run with SecurityManager?

Comment: @Tarlog, added stack trace (and one question to main post) for the exception what is thrown when I run the app with system properties you provided. (I just changed the port to 43030 in -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port)

Comment: @Tarlog, by the way, when not running my app with these params so the exception is not thrown on my local machine I tried opening jconsole and select the app by process id and it worked out like a charm. However accessing it with the url didn't work..

Comment: @Tarlog, can you check if my service url is correct? I really don't understand why there has to be localhost and my ip in it and a /test in the end. What should the remote url I enter in jconsole to connect look like?

Comment: @Tarlog, I doubt I run with any securityManager. Haven't seen anything like that in my app.

Comment: See if this thread helps: http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-26140.html

Comment: I had the com.sun.management.jmxremote properties mentioned set - but still got the AccessException - I then replaced my use of the RmiRegistryFactoryBean in Spring with a call to  LocateRegistry.createRegistry(jmxPort) - and I could register my mbeans without getting exceptions. The problem only occurred for me when running my war inside an embedded Jetty (for integrationtest). When I deployed my war in other app servers I was allowed to register my mbeans. It seems like Jetty (9) auto creates a remote rmiregistry on the com.sun.management.jmxremote.port but with other security settings

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to set alwaysCreate on your RMI bean like so:

```
    <bean id="rmiRegistry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
        <property name="alwaysCreate" value="true" />
    </bean>
```

This prevents the bean from attempting a connection to find an existing RMI registry.

Comment: That was not enough in my case (Spring 3.2.5). I had to stop using the RmiRegistryFactoryBean and use registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(jmxPort); before I was allowed to register anything.